# Continue plotting from the previous result in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using `quiver` to plot velocity vectors. I want to generate a plot that will include the results of five iterations. Here is an image of the velocity vectors plotted separately for each iteration:

[image: image of the velocity vectors plotted separately]

If I use `hold on`, all the plots start from same point and therefore the images overlap. I want to plot the second image from the point where the first image ends and third image from the point where the second image ends, and so on. I have written this small code:

```
for i=1:5  
    figure;  
    for it=o:nt  
        %hold on  
        quiver(x,y,u,v);  
        drawnow;  
    end  
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"...from the point where the first image ends"*?

Comment: Can you clarify the role of the second loop with `it`, i.e. how it influences `x`/`y`?

Comment: I would start an empty quiver plot before the loop and partially set data in the loop.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez 2nd loop is a time loop, which moves from 0 to nt with increments of dt which i have initialized. This loop creates matrix u and v.

Comment: @rayryeng, I have just edited my post and have added an image, as you can see, all images are starting from the same point (the lower left point), I am using a finite difference scheme which increments with time as well as with space.  I want to start the 2nd image from the point where the 1st image ends(2nd image top row is the 2nd image), the 2nd image should start from the right end of the first image.

Comment: Perhaps what you'd want to do is create one quiver plot in the very first loop iteration with `qh=quiver(...);` and then update `qh.UData` and `qh.VData` in the other iterations?

Comment: @zeeMonkeez I dint understand on how to update my quiver, I tried to change the x and y but while doing so images are being plotted in different coordinate system, sorry i am a beginner

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're truing to do either. "I want to start the 2nd image from the point where the 1st image ends" – all of your axes have the same limits so Idn't know what you mean by this. Do you want to erase the result from the previous iteration and update the figure with the new result (effectively animation)?

Comment: @horchler; lets say my first loop generates a straight line from (0,0) to (4,4). and my 2nd iteration generates a straight line of length 2sqrt(2) cm and same angle as that of the 1st line. If i just plot my 2nd iteration in the separate figure it will start from (0,0) and end at (2,2). What i want is that my 2nd figure should start from (4,4)[which is the point where the 1st figure end].